# Apex:InlineEditSupport displays unexpected text

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I want to use apex:InlineEditSupport to change the name of a record (displayed as a card on a wall) in a custom VisualForce page. The inline editing works fine but a text appears in the VF-page.

[image]

It appears to be some kind of JavaScript or a kind of Pseudocode displaying information about the records displayed at the VF-page.

I used the apex:InlineEditSupport without any parameters.

[image]

Has anyone ever experienced something similar or knows how to get rid of this? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out? Perhaps a conflict with jQuery is the cause?